# How can I build a "Metro looking" website?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7, javascript

I would like to build a small web site with mostly static content (a User's Guide actually) using Javascript libraries. If I had to use a server-side language, I would use C# (either ASP .Net or MVC) with Visual Studio since I already know how to build a complex web site with this infrastructure.

However I would like to use the Metro looking aspect because I find it really nice and would be appropriate to this kind of web site. I know that Visual Studio 2012 is coming with a nice template to build Metro looking websites but it's only available on Windows 8 Preview because of the need to use the WinRT libraries, correct ?

Therefore, I am looking for existing Javascript libraries that would do the trick for me as I would develop it on Windows 7/Visual Studio 2010.

Thanks a lot !